# Dynamic coordinates google maps wouldn't load

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I'm trying to make google maps appears in my website, but the coordinates is displayed dynamically based on database. Here is my code

**HTML :**

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        Maps
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body" id="maps-area" style="height: 500px;" onLoad="loadMap(<?=$row->maps;?>)">
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript :**

```
function loadMap(x)
{
    var mapOptions =
    {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(x),
        zoom: 17,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("maps-area"), mapOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker
    ({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(x),
    });
    marker.setMap(map);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", loadMap);
```

**Load Maps API :**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

But the maps is wouldn't appears. Can anyone tell where is wrong from my code? Thanks before :)

Comment: what does <?=$row->maps;?> contains?

Comment: @DharaParmar the coordinates : -7.567472,110.796774 (for example)

Comment: I cant find any element with id maps-mata-lomba in your provided html...is it exist in html?

Comment: @DharaParmar Sorry wrong when I post, I just edited

Comment: You can not use onload on div element, it should be used on body tag..Instead of calling loadMap() on div element, try to call that function on document.ready();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working version... all i changed is...

```
<?=$row->maps;?>// i guess this doesn't work as expected??
```

following is the working version... i hard coded your lat long(taken from your comment)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function loadMap() {
            var mapOptions = {
                center : new google.maps.LatLng(-7.567472,110.796774),
                zoom : 17,
                mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("maps-area"), mapOptions);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position : new google.maps.LatLng(x),
            });
            marker.setMap(map);
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", loadMap);
    </script>
</body>
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">Maps</div>
    <div class="panel-body" id="maps-area" style="height: 500px;" onLoad="loadMap()"></div>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: Happy to have helped you... :)